# how to filter all string sequence in array using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I have a large array, and I want to filter it based on a string I pass it. This string could be one or two characters, up to an entire string.

Here's an example array:

```
var data = ["bourbon", "beer", "electric"]
```

If I pass `e`, I want the result `["electric", "beer"]`.

How can I achieve this functionality?

Comment: What code have you tried that isn't working? What is the `beer` object that you're referencing?

Comment: I think he wanted to write `'beer', 'electric'`.

Comment: I can barely understand a single sentence. Please edit the question so it would be more understandable and clear what you are asking about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `filter` with `includes`:

```js
var data = ["bourbon", "beer", "electric"];
const selectByLetter = l => data.filter(s => s.includes(l));
console.log(selectByLetter("e"));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

ES5 syntax:

```js
var data = ["bourbon", "beer", "electric"];
var selectByLetter = function(l) {
  return data.filter(function(s) {
    return s.indexOf(l) > -1;
  });
}
console.log(selectByLetter("e"));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

Comment: @ jack Bashford I tried to run this code its showing beer ,electric but I want electric ,beer how to achieve it

Comment: So, you want to sort it in reverse alphabetical order?

Comment: I want this type of output .can you please refer this link https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_lists.asp

Comment: But **how** is it sorted? Currently it's in the order provided in the array - should the output be reversed?

Comment: no I am asking same search bar functionality sorted the array .

Answer (score 0):

you can use underscore.

```js
var data = ["bourbon","beer", "electric"]
var filtered = [];
var filter = function(value) {
  filtered = _.filter(data, function(el) {
    return el.indexOf(value)
  })
  return filtered;
}

console.log('filtered',filter('e'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = ["bourbon","beer", "electric"]
var result = data.filter(c => /e/i.test(c))
console.log('data',result);
```

Answer (score 0):

For an `O(N)` solution instead of `O(N^2)`, use a Set instead (`Set.has` is `O(1)`, whereas `String.prototype.includes` is `O(N)`):

```js
const data = ["bourbon", "beer", "electric"];
const setByData = data.reduce((a, str) => {
  a[str] = new Set(str);
  return a;
}, {});
console.log(
  Object.entries(setByData)
    .filter(([, set]) => set.has('e'))
    .map(([str]) => str)
);
```

Comment: @ CertainPerformance once I pass the string method I want this type of output.can you please refer this https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_filter_list

Comment: What do you mean? What exactly is the object structure you're looking for, can you describe it?

Comment: array['beer','bourbon,'electric'']. pass string "e" first its check first occurrence then second occurrence .['electric','beer'] i want this type of output.how to achieve it

Answer (score 0):

```
products_name = ['ebay','eaby','ebb','ebbe','eaab','eeb']  
search_options = []  
const searched_word = "eb";  
for (const key in products_name)   
{  
    const search_count = products_name[key].search(new RegExp(searched_word, "i"));    
    if (search_count != -1)   
    {  
        search_options.push(products_name[key])  
    }  
}
console.log(search_options)
```